# when i put \dt command it s not showing me any table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I don't understand what's wrong and why the program is not working.
I am watching a tutorial for spring boots beginners Java framework and I got stuck at this 2 errors from the pictures . And I really don't understand why it's appearing. I have a problem with database even if i connect in terminal when i put `\dt` command it s not showing me any table, and another error when i run the program, and i don t understand why I am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the schema that contains the tables is not on your`search_path`.

Comment: And do you have any idea, how can i fix that?

Comment: What if you do \dt *? It should show at least the system tables in schema `pg_catalog`. User tables if they exist are probably going to show up in schema `public`.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource  and for this?

Comment: I suggest that you read the psql documentation on pattern matching.

Comment: You have two questions here: 1) Finding tables using `psql` 2) Using `Spring Boot`. You should create a new Stack Overflow question for 2) as it is really a Java question.

Answer (score 1):

`\dt` shows all tables on your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH). You can specify an argument that is a pattern that matches table names. To display *all* tables (including system catalogs and other internal data), use

```
\dt *.*
```